# Applescript will not quit automatically

Tags: applescript

Is there any way I can make it so my script will automatically close? Note: if you force quit it, the screensaver stays on the desktop, so it is not because it is being run within the app.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell screen saver preferences
        if running then
            do shell script "killall ScreenSaverEngine"
        else
            do shell script "//System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine -background"
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `&> /dev/null &` to the shell script:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell screen saver preferences
        if running then
            do shell script "killall ScreenSaverEngine"
        else
            do shell script "//System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine -background  &> /dev/null &"
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```